# Intranet Live maps Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, maps, intranet

I'm creating an intranet website and i have a couple of asp.net textboxes/ddl that make up a persons code.
What i need help with is displaying a map based on the address. Any examples on how to do this would be very helpfuul.

I tried to get a google maps api key but you need a internet web site to get one.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you can put any website address in the Google API signup!

I have done something similiar in .net and once you figure out the map api its fairly to get working.

Checkout the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/index.html).

Here is the [reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html).

Comment: So, it doesn't check if the website address is valid or not?

Comment: Hmm that's new. And is it fully functional?

Comment: I am not sure. I was plotting way points and calculating directions!